# Add rel="noopener" to links/anchors in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

When a user creates an anchor element in WYSIWYG view, I want to automatically insert `rel="noopener"` to the HTML.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dataProcessor` to force the way the elements are build:

```
dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
    elements: {
        a: function( el ) {
            if ( !el.attributes.rel) {
                el.attributes['rel'] = 'noopener';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/25x37LgL/